# I have a problem with persistent page links

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem with Permanent link. All my pages have the same name with a counter number

like this link : `http://test.mysite.com:8080/CNC/murt-28`

(**murt**) This word is repeated in all links but carries a different counter

When i change it from the WordPress editor, it return to the same old link that holds the word (**murt**) after i reload the page.

I hope you will help me solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: Do you click update after you change the permalink?

Comment: yes... i click update

Comment: Did you check your settings->Permalinks? Maybe it's set from there

Comment: How did i check that ??

Comment: Go into your admin panel, open the Settings section in the left side and click Permalinks. See what the permalink structure is, eventually change it to `https://www.example.com/exemple-article/`